# Tool to measure SD card access time on my Windows laptop?

Tags: windows, gratis

I was wondering of I could use an SD card as extra RAM. I suspect it would be way too slow (maybe I can use it as a swap file instead).

Who can recommend a good, gratis Windows app to test measure the SD card's access time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access times for SD cards depend on a number of factors:

- Class, Size & Brand of SD card *(obviously a class 3 will be slower than class 10 but some manufacturers are better than others)*
- Interface details *(if you are using a low specification SD card reader/writer via USB 1 you have no chance)*
- Mostly Reading or Mostly Writing *(SD cards are usually much slower for write than read)*
- File size(s), file system on the drive & any fragmentation.
- Your operating system and drivers (of course).

Camera Memory Speed gives some useful [benchmarks](https://www.cameramemoryspeed.com/reviews/sd-cards/).

It is also worth noting that all *or almost all* SD cards are known to have a finite number of write operations at a given location before failure.

For Windows users I would recommend the tool from [UsbFlashSpeed.com](http://usbflashspeed.com/) which is free, portable and tests at multiple file sizes.

My personal suggestion is not to use an SD card for a swap drive, (frequent writes, speed crucial and stability critical), nor for anything that gets written to frequently but they are ideal for storing archival material and reference material *just make sure that you make regular backup copies.*

Answer (score 2):

Some versions of Windows can use an SD card to boost performance; google READYBOOST for more information.  Wikipedia's article on it is here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost

Out of curiosity, I once tried running a couple of virtual machines from a fast SD card, an external USB3 7200 rpm HDD and the internal HDD (also 7200 rpm).  The external HDD's performance wasn't as good as the internal drive's, but it was quite usable for my purposes.  The SD was impossibly slow.

Comment: That's some very useful info there. Thanks. I look forward to seeing your contributions on this site & others. Welcome aboard!  I'll leave it a day or two for possible other answers. If no one posts, I will accept this.

Comment: I pretty much agree on everything. Also ReadyBoost tend to help improve performance when the computer is critically low on RAM, but once you have more than 1GB it produces little practical difference. At that point, upgrading RAM is more worthwhile.